# NFS4 ID Mapping

Tags: nfs, nfs4

Currently using NFS4 idmapping.  If i manually update the file "**/sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping"** on the NFS Server to "**N**" and flush the cache the UID and GID show up correctly on the NFS client.  The issue is on reboot it seems to change this file back to "**Y**"

The soluction "**try to enforce numeric ID's on the server: echo "options nfs nfs4_disable_idmapping=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf and reboot NFS server.**" did not seem to help. I even tried nfs4_disable_idmapping=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specifying the wrong module. As you want to configure nfs server, then you have to provide the option for **nfsd** module:

```
echo "options nfsd nfs4_disable_idmapping=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/nfsd.conf
```

Note that this should be "options nfsd" for the server module (not "options nfs").

Comment: AWW that and I set it to options nfsd nfs4_disable_idmapping=0 did the trick.