# sshfs file writes don't respect UID/GID mapping

Tags: linux, home-directory, sshfs

I'm mounting my /home directory remotely using sshfs. Since UIDs and GIDs aren't the same on the server and client, I'm using `idmap=file`. Additionally, because of application requirements, I must mount all of /home rather than individual user directories.

sshfs_uids:

```
user1:1001
user2:1000
```

sshfs_gids:

```
user1:1001
user2:1000
```

Command to mount:

```
sudo sshfs -o nonempty -o transform_symlinks -o hard_remove -o allow_other -o nomap=ignore -o idmap=file -o uidfile=/root/sshfs_uids -o gidfile=/root/sshfs_gids root@myserver:/home /home
```

When reading files, everything works as expected (files that should be owned by user1:user1 are indeed so). However, when I write as user1, this happens:

```
user1@myclient:~$ touch foo
user1@myclient:~$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 13 13:54 foo
```

My user writes files as root! Even doing a `ls -l` from myserver turns up the same root ownership. I can fix it manually, though:

```
user1@myclient:~$ chown user1:user1 foo
user1@myclient:~$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--. 1 user1 user1 0 Jun 13 13:54 foo
```

Is it possible, using a sshfs or fuser option, to make it such that new files are owned by the user that created them? If not, can I make sshfs or fuser call a custom script every time a file is written so that I can fix the file's ownership using chown?

**EDIT:**
If neither of the above are possible, can anyone recommend some alternative remote filesystem software that is:

secure for use over the public internet

transparent (after setup) to users/scripts (so not plain scp)

Comment: You are logging in as `root` -> `root@my_server`. What do you expect? Works as designed.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I assume you mean to say that my first question about an option to automatically set my desired ownership is a no-go. How about the callback script? How about an alternative solution?

Comment: Has it to be a *...file system software that use ssh keys...*? Why not use NFS or Samba?

Comment: @Thomas, The server and client are separated over the open internet, so I would have to find some other way of securing it such as going through a VPN or using Kerberos with NFS. I'm open to running things through a VPN as a last resort (downside is it's slow). From what I've read, Kerberos seems like more trouble than it's worth, not only in its setup but also its usage. But you're right, I'll edit the question to relax my requirements on alternative software.

Comment: This seems like a bug in `sshfs`.

Answer (score 1):

the issue in this case is the fact that you are connecting as root

```
root@myserver:/home /home
```

for reading, it retrieves the information as is, but when you write, the system will write using the user that you have.

Keep in you mind, that the server is writing the data, so it will write using the user that connected to it. The solution is connect using the user and its credentials that you do want to write data using:

```
user1@myserver:/home /home
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you were trying to mount sshfs with root (sudo) hence your files will be created with the user the filesystem was mounted.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else having a similar issue, I found that ssh-tunneling nfs did the trick.

**/etc/exports on `myserver`:**

```
/home localhost(insecure,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

**/etc/idmap.conf on `myserver` and `myclient` ([citation](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/nfs-mounts-always-as-user-nobody-on-centos-4175419723/)):**

```
...
Domain = localdomain
...
```

**/etc/modprobe.d/nfsd.conf on `myserver`:**

```
options nfsd nfs4_disable_idmapping=0
```

**/etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf on `myclient`:**

```
options nfs nfs4_disable_idmapping=0
```

The above two files set `/sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` and `/sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` to "N" on boot ([citation](https://serverfault.com/questions/766869/nfs4-id-mapping)).

Either reboot, or restart nfs/idmap related services on both machines and run `nfsidmap -c`. Then, [tunnel the connection](https://gist.github.com/proudlygeek/5721498):

```
user1@myclient:~$ ssh -fN -L 3049:localhost:2049 user1@myserver
user1@myclient:~$ sudo mount -t nfs4 -o port=3049 localhost:/home /home
```

At this point, the firewall for `myserver` only has to be open on port 22, and the nfs traffic will be as secure as ssh.

**EDIT:**
This didn't work, but only appeared to work. Apparently, while one might think that idmap should map IDs, it doesn't. At least, it only does so at a high level, so certain operations slip past.